Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'any[]' in vue3
in a vue3 's code
const jobs = ref([]);

async function getQueueJobs(status: string) {
  let result = await request({
    url: '/api/v1/jobs',
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });
  jobs.value = result['data'];
  console.log('......', jobs.value);
}

compiling with errors saying

Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

tried with
const jobs = ref(any[]);

compiling with errors saying

An element access expression should take an argument.

how to deal with this compiling issue ?

What is request()? Please [edit] your question to provide details

Ideally, you'll add appropriate types for both your Ref and result data
properties.
The ref is simple (assuming there's a Job type defined)
const jobs = ref<Job[]>([]);

See https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api#typing-ref
Typing the result data depends on what request() is but since it defaults to unknown, you can simply cast it
jobs.value = result.data as Job[];


Assuming request() is axios() (it bears all the hallmarks), you can easily type the response data by providing a generic override.
Also, GET is the default and such requests have no body so therefore have no need for a content-type header
jobs.value = (await request<Job[]>('/api/v1/jobs')).data;

